# How to solve "Your target is built for tvOS but contains embedded content built for the watchOS (XXXX Watch App.app), which is not allowed"?

Tags: ios, tvos, watchos

I would like to create a basic app (a list and a detail view for each row) using SwiftUI, and which would target iOS, macOS, tvOS and even watchOS.

I initially created a target allowing iOS, macOS and tvOS. Everything compiles fine.

Then, I tried adding a new target specific to watchOS, by doing so:

Targets > + > watchOS > App > then I chose "Watch App for existing iOS app", and finally created the target. And this is where I'm now getting this issue, when I try to compile both targets:

> Your target is built for tvOS but contains embedded content built for the watchOS platform (My-iOS-Target Watch App.app), which is not allowed.

Could you explain what's wrong, and how can I solve this issue? Also, what are some good practices about this? (I'm experienced with iOS/macOS, but I don't know very well tvOS and watchOS).

Thanks for your help!